# Parse string to n-gram without using for loop - R

Tags: r, parsing, for-loop, lapply

I want to write a function that would divide a string into a list of trigrams e.g.

```
"JOHNSTEWART" --> chr [1:9] "JOH" "OHN" "HNS" "NST" "STE" "TEW" "EWA" "WAR" "ART"
```

I can write this using a for loop,

```
ngram_function <- function(x){
  if(!is.na(x)&(nchar(x)>2)){
    ngram <- rep("n", n= nchar(x)-3+1)
    for (i in c(1:nchar(x)-2)){
      ngram[i] <-(substr(x, start =i,stop= i-1+3))
    }
    return(ngram)
  }
  else{
     return(x)
  }
}
```

But it takes long time to scale for large number of values, is there any other R-optimized version to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a version using `sapply`:

```
myfun <- function(x, n){
  sapply(1:(nchar(x)-n+1), function(z) substr(x, z, z+n-1))
}

myfun("JOHNSTEWART", 3)
[1] "JOH" "OHN" "HNS" "NST" "STE" "TEW" "EWA" "WAR" "ART"
myfun("JOHNSTEWART", 4)
[1] "JOHN" "OHNS" "HNST" "NSTE" "STEW" "TEWA" "EWAR" "WART"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `substr` and `mapply`:

```
string <- "JOHNSTEWART"
nc <- nchar(string)

mapply(function(x, y){substr(string, x, y)}, x=1:(nc-2), y=3:nc)
# [1] "JOH" "OHN" "HNS" "NST" "STE" "TEW" "EWA" "WAR" "ART"
```